# Me muestra más de una notificación al ejecutarlo

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Estoy utilizando el [plugin Bootstrap-Notify de remabledesigns](http://bootstrap-notify.remabledesigns.com/)
para generar notificaciones con más estilo. Llamo la notificación a través de un checkbox pero, al llamar la función, en vez de mostrar una notificación me muestra 3. ¿Cómo puedo solucionar eso?

Acá mi código

```js
$('#pzNo').change(function() {
  if ($('#pzSi').attr('checked', 'true')) {
    $('#divzona').css('display', 'none');
    $('#pzSi').removeAttr('checked');
  }
  $.notify("Hello World"); // aca se genera la notificacion

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mouse0270-bootstrap-notify/3.1.7/bootstrap-notify.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="pzNo" id="pzNo"/>
```

Comment: Hola Pablo, el código proporcionado no es suficiente para ver un posible error. Deberías crear un [mcve] para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: como lo puedo hacer? es una librería y no tiene cdn para incluir el link :(

Comment: He puesto tu código como ejecutable creando un [mcve], pero el problema no se puede reproducir: sólo se muestra un mensaje de notificación. ¿Puede que te falte por agregar código a la pregunta?

Comment: Falta código. Si se ejecuta 3 veces puede ser porque estés haciendo bind varias veces del evento change en ese objeto.

Comment: lo voy a verificar muchas gracias y le comento como me va

Answer (score 0):

Al final el problema fue un descuido ya que la libreria estaba siendo llamada mas de 2 veces por lo que al llamar el evento se activa y llamaba mas de una vez